# Is there an R function that can plot the PACF() of an ARIMA model in the fable, feasts or fpp3 packages?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, fable-r

I am working with a tsibble created from a csv file and I have begun following along Rob Hyndman's fpp3 [textbook](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-r.html) creating ARIMA models with the [fable](https://fable.tidyverts.org/) package. **My goal is to plot the PACF of the given ARIMA model.** This is inspired by following along a Duke University [article](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ernau/411arim3.htm) that details how to find the correct ARIMA() arguments by looking at the ACF() and PACF() plots of the time series, and then of the ARIMA models.
I can plot the PACF(), but only of the time series "global_economy", which comes with the tsibble package. And then when it comes to plotting the residuals of my model, I can only view the ACF(). I am not sure if there is another function that returns the PACF() values in a table output. **Has anyone plotted the PACF() of your model in R, using these packages below?**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)
library(tsibble)
library(feasts)

global_economy %>%
  filter(Code == "CAF") %>%
  gg_tsdisplay(difference(Exports), plot_type='partial', lag_max = 36)

caf_fit <- global_economy %>%
  filter(Code == "CAF") %>%
  model(arima000 = ARIMA(Exports ~ pdq(0,0,0)),
        arima210 = ARIMA(Exports ~ pdq(2,1,0)),
        arima013 = ARIMA(Exports ~ pdq(0,1,3)),
        stepwise = ARIMA(Exports),
        search = ARIMA(Exports, stepwise=FALSE))

caf_fit %>% select(.model = arima000) %>% gg_tsresiduals(lag = 36)
```

[ACF and PACF of my tsibble using gg_tsdisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75dc2.png),
[residuals plot of my ARIMA(0,0,0) model using gg_tsresiduals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbMsC.png)

In summary: I have only been able to plot the PACF() of my tsibble. The gg_tsresiduals() function also only returns the ACF() plot of the ARIMA model. My goal is to plot the PACF() of the given ARIMA model. So far I can't find any documentation that can help with this.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Lupercio, could you please share your data using `dput(bx_ts)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Hey @Quinten, I have instead edited my question. I am using a tsibble provided by the tsibble package, for easier reproducibility.

Comment: Great, but without reproducible data we can’t help you easily. Could you please provide your data in the question?

Comment: Users can use the global_economy data can when the tsibble library is loaded. My original data went through some feature engineering to get to this point, that I think I can replicate the results instead with the data and code provided in the question.